# Why am I getting an error telling me my table's name is incorrect?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm building my database with Entity Framework and it works when I run it on localhost.

Unfortunately, when I publish to my webhost's server, I can't have the database initialize because they refuse to grant the SQL user rights to drop or create the database so my initializer looks like like:

```
Database.SetInitializer<OrtundEntities>(null);
```

Normally, the MVC project should ideally seed some default data into the database (such as user roles, users, etc) so that I have a login with which to test and eventually manage my data.

I've had to disable this as well so my global.asax.cs file looks like this:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        OrtundEntities db = new OrtundEntities();
        db.Database.Initialize(true);

        // add default user accounts and other default data into the database
        //db.Seed();
    }
```

Unfortunately, when I try to visit the URL for the site online, I get the following error.

**Error text:**

> Invalid object name 'dbo.UserRoles'

I changed this model's name from `Roles` to `UserRoles` as I thought that maybe the first name was conflicting with a SQL keyword. My DbSets are below:

```
    public DbSet<POSProvider> POSProviders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Receipt> Receipts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Reward> Rewards { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Store> Stores { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
```

The UserRole model looks like this (all of this is exact copy/paste)

```
public class UserRole : GenericServiceModel
{
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
}
```

GenericServiceModel looks like this (I'll be adding more into this as it may make sense to do so:

```
public class GenericServiceModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
}
```

**Stack trace**

> [SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'dbo.UserRoles'.]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +388
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +717
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +4515
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() +61
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +134
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +6557689
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader
>   ds) +6560327
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean asyncWrite) +586
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method) +104
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method) +288
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior) +171
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget
>   target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext,
>   Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +208
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand
>   command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +438
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand
>   entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior) +53
>
> [EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing
>   the command definition. See the inner exception for details.]
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand
>   entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior) +155
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute(ObjectContext
>   context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues) +1117
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction(Func`1
>   func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean
>   startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess) +516
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()
>   +170      System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1
>   operation) +263
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1
>   forMergeOption) +268
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
>   +11      System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext() +50      System.Linq.Enumerable.Single(IEnumerable`1 source) +188
>
>   System.Linq.Queryable.Any(IQueryable`1 source) +298
>   OrtundService.Models.OrtundEntities.Seed() +649
>   OrtundService.MvcApplication.Application_Start() +382
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): An error occurred while executing the
>   command definition. See the inner exception for details.]
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext
>   context, HttpApplication app) +12601645
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +175
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +304
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +404
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +475
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): An error occurred while executing the
>   command definition. See the inner exception for details.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +12618692
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +159      System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +12458309

I can't see any problem in the data model or even on the generated database so I don't have any clue where to go or what to do for a resolution.

I executed the following query on my dev server:

```
SELECT TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_DEFAULT
FROM ortund.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'UserRoles';
GO
```

It gives me the following results:

```
TABLE_CATALOG   TABLE_SCHEMA    TABLE_NAME  COLUMN_NAME COLUMN_DEFAULT  
ortund  dbo UserRoles   Id  NULL  
ortund  dbo UserRoles   RoleName    NULL  
ortund  dbo UserRoles   Deleted NULL
```

Can anyone tell me what's going on here? Where does the error come from?

**EDIT**

My user model links UserRole for a structured relationship between the 2 tables:

```
public class User : GenericServiceModel
{
    public UserRole Role { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public decimal RewardTotal { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this http://forums.asp.net/t/1977214.aspx?Mvc+5+Identity+Error+Invalid+object+name+dbo+AspNetUsers+

Comment: is your application pointing at the correct database?

Comment: @user1666620 yes, I'm using the web.config connectionstring named "DefaultConnection" which currently uses the connection string supplied to me by the web host

Comment: Are you having two areas like main and administrator?

Comment: [HttpException (0x80004005): An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.].. what is in inner exception?

Comment: @AasishKr.Sharma it's the next one up. Read the stack trace backwards (bottom to top) and it'll make sense

Answer (score 0):

Had the web host check the database schema with the same SQL query I posted here and they confirmed the table didn't exist.

It seems like they restored an out of date backup of the database onto the server which didn't have the table but since the correct backup has been restored, everything works just fine.